# Is Xolvio:cleaner package needed when testing in Meteor.js with Cypress.io?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, cypress

I am implementing testing in Meteor.js using Cypress. The Meteor documentation recommends downloading xolvio:cleaner package for cleaning the database, but I am not sure if this is needed when using Cypress. Also, I am having a hard time locating the routes when using Meteor - is there a way to inspect the network and verify the routes for testing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: It depends. Does your test require you to clear the database for it to work properly? Though, most likely xolvio:cleaner is meant to be used for unit or integration testing; not end-to-end testing which is what Cypress for. Second, you trouble with finding routes. What routes are you trying to locate? What for? Can you give us an example? Also, what's the routing library used React Router or Flow Router? Always try to explain and offer a little research so we can quickly pinpoint the problem. Good luck!

Comment: https://dev.to/splitified/test-your-meteor-app-with-docker-jenkins-and-cypress-part-1-12om